# Which Android version of Tor Browser should I choose for my Android devices?

Tags: android

There are four versions offered: aarch64, arm, x86_x64, and x86. Now, I should probably look somewhere in device settings for an answer. Where precisely to look?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related on Android.SE: [How to tell what architecture an APK is intended for?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/168302/44325) and [How to get hardware specs of Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/6372/44325)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Orbot's Source Code](https://github.com/guardianproject/orbot/blob/master/app/build.gradle#L18-L19), which is an official Android Tor Browser, we know that:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16 
    targetSdkVersion 31
  }
}
```

By SDK version number from [wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history), we can conclude that Tor on Android has requirements as below.

- Minimum Android Version: JellyBean 4.1
- Recommended Android Version: Android 12

**EDIT**: If you need to see Android version for specific Tor Browser version, see [tags](https://github.com/guardianproject/orbot/tags) then go to file `app/build.gradle` at "view code"

Comment: Do note that Orbot is not a browser. *IT IS NOT Tor Browser*. Tor Browser is based of fenix/firefox for android, which requires Android 5.0 or newer: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/android/99.0/system-requirements/